# Run RMI program from another java program

Tags: java

I need to start RMI server object java code from another java executable. When I try to run the main java program which calls the RMI java program using exec() function, I get ClassDefNotFound error. I am using eclipse. However, if i run the RMI program directly from console it works.

Can someone please help me to solve the issue.

Thank you

Comment: ClassDefNotFoundError naming what class?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to start RMI server object java code from another java
>   executable.

Why? Why write two programs when one will do? Just export the remote object(s) from the 'other' Java program.

Comment: I need to run n RMI objects at the same item. So, I am using another program to take n as input and launch rmi server programs which will register n different objects with different names.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to simulate a situation of n servers running on different systesms.

Comment: @MuppaDivya That doesn't actually answer the question. Why can't you export all the remote objects from a single JVM?

Comment: Because I need to have n servers running on n different JVM. My experiment needs to run on n different systems and they need to communicate. So, I am simulating that on n different JVM and they need to registry their objects with rmi so that they can communicate.

Comment: Could someone please help me with the issue.